# Is it important to follow one of the four mazhab in Islam?

Tags: madhhab

As the majority of Muslims follows one of the four great imam in Islam, is it really important to follow them? Do everyone of us has the ability to solve our daily matters in the light of Quran and Hadith.
I am asking this question because some of my friends are arguing with me that it is not important to follow the four great imams.

Comment: No its not.... these are divisions created by Muslims ....basically we should strive to follow the correct teachings (that are based on Quran and Sahih Hadith) of each Madhab without sticking to one Madhab. The imaams never intended to create dibisions in the Ummah . Nor did the Prophet  (peace be upon him) ever told us to follow any particular Islamic sect . Follow Islam , be a good Muslim striving to attain Knowledge and you won't be sinning by not sticking to one Madhab In sha Allah

Comment: Divisions******

Answer (score -1):

We should **follow them all** as much as we can , **not stick to one** of them.

Why?
As:

-They reached a great level of islamic knowledge and fiqh you can't find today among most scholars.

-Since they lived at an age without great fetnah (temptation), as today, at islam, shari'ah and faith, so their fiqh is more likely to be accurate, near to be right

When we have khillaf (disagreement) between them on a point, I think we shouldn't stick on one opinion, It's better to pick the nearest one to be right

Bad thing to tight our minds and leave the whole picture.